# Вывод результата в java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Возможно очень глупый вопрос, но где мой вывод текста? Уже долго мучаюсь с этой мелочью)[image: ???????????]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Судя по сообщению, вы проект компилируете, но не запускаете.

Comment: Попробуй по другому: `String a = "Hello world!"; System.out.println(a);`

Comment: @YagorG Как добавление переменной может помочь?

Comment: Распишите, пожалуйста, подробнее всю последовательность действий: какой тип проекта? как собирается? как запускается?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, в данном случае скриншот лучше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась сама по себе, никаких действий не предпринимал. Через несколько дней ещё раз запустил проект и всё заработало. Наверное, программирование - это магия)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]